# jQuery File Upload resize uploaded image

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, yii2, jquery-file-upload, yii2-extension

Hi guys i'm using this plugin for file upload [2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget) based on [BlueImp jQuery File Upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Like in the guide i configured all right and all actions work well but i have a question.

- **Is there an option for resize an uploaded image?**

When i upload an image from the queue files(third image in the example) that image is returned in original size and not in a small size. Is there an option for resize the already uploaded image like first and second images that are in the queue?
I think there is a `clientOption` for this but I can not find anything.
Help me guys!

**Image Example:** 
[image: issue image preview]

**Widget configuration:**

```
<?= \dosamigos\fileupload\FileUploadUI::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'image',
    'url' => ['site/image-upload'],
    'fieldOptions' => [
        'accept' => 'image/*'
    ],
    'clientOptions' => [
        'maxFileSize' => 2000000,
    ],
    'clientEvents' => [
        'fileuploaddone' => 'function(e, data) {
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log(data);
                }',
        'fileuploadfail' => 'function(e, data) {
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log(data);
                }',
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: I've never used that library but I found this in the documentation; [Client side Image Resizing](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing).

Comment: Resizing via CSS is not sufficient?

Comment: The documentaion file you linked up help me...thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should do it after uploaded to your server in controller ! ( actionUpload)